# Columns Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

So, i'm working on Image Gallery with Bootstrap...
Problem is i can't make four images two on top, three under the top ones and on the left corner vertical image. You can see in the image i have four images placed okay but vertical one is under them...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img class="img-responsive col-md-4" src="img/gallery/potok.jpg">
            <img class="img-responsive col-md-4" src="img/gallery/potok.jpg">
            <img class="img-responsive col-md-4" src="img/gallery/potok.jpg">
            <img class="img-responsive col-md-4" src="img/gallery/potok.jpg">
            <img class="img-responsive col-md-4" src="img/gallery/potok.jpg">
            <img class="img-responsive col-md-4" src="img/gallery/potok.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img class="img-responsive col-md-5" src="img/gallery/simon.jpg">
            <img class="img-responsive col-md-5" src="img/gallery/simon.jpg">
        </div>
</div>
```

What should i try?   [here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNTfg.jpg)

Comment: can't understand your request exactly. can you illustrate a simple example of how images should be displayed?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/H17hTO6 like this

Answer (score 1):

You may imbricate class and elements ;

possible example

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x600" class="col-4">
    <div class="row wrap col-8">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x330" class="mb-auto col-6">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x330" class="mb-auto col-6">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x450" class="mt-auto col-4">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x450" class="mt-auto col-4">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x450" class="mt-auto col-4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion

```css
.col {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 200px;
}

.col-4 {
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.col-4,
.col {
  background-image: url(https://www.cowgirlcontractcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/360/2018/05/placeholder-img-3.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4"></div>
</div>
```